# Matching one column into the other in numerical order in R

Tags: r

I have a datafile:

```
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/example.csv
```

Read file:

```
example<-read.csv("example.csv")
example<-example[,-1]
```

example[,1] contains a list of numbers increasing in numerical order.
example[,2] contains another set of numbers

First I would like to identify the numbers in example[,2] that are no listed in example[,1]

```
diff<-setdiff(example[,2],example[,1])
```

Now that I know these values I would like to insert them into example[,1] leaving existing values in example[,1] and example[,2] intact.

A short example would be:

```
Example[,1]   Example[,2]
1             1000
1             50
1             3
1             90
1             25
3             4
5             2
5             7
etc           etc
```

After I run setdiff() I get the numbers not in the first column but in the second.

Now I would like to place them in example[,1] to produce the following output:

```
Example[,1]   Example[,2]
1             1000
1             50
1             3
1             90
1             25
2             NA
3             4
4             NA
5             2
5             7
etc           etc
```

So basically placing them in numerical order but leaving everything else intact.

Part 1 excellently solved by **Joris Meys**!

I have two further questions:

/////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////

1:

Can the same be done if there is an additional third column but I don't want to do anything with it?

e.g.:

ORIGINAl

```
 Example[,1]   Example[,2] Example[,3]
 1             1000        37
 1             50          18
 1             3           54
 1             90          72
 1             25          23
 3             4           15
 5             2           20
 5             7           9
 etc           etc
```

Desired OUTPUT:

```
Example[,1]   Example[,2]  Example[,3]
1             1000         37
1             50           18
1             3            54
1             90           72
1             25           23
2             NA           NA
3             4            15
4             NA           NA
5             2            20
5             7            19
etc           etc
```

2:

Instead of adding NA in example[,2] to cases where example[,1] doesnt have the value from example[,2] for example example[,1] doesn't have number '30' then I would like to search for whether example[,2] has number'30'and see what value example[,1] has in that row then add it to example[,2] instead of the NA's.

for example:

```
Example[,1]   Example[,2]  Example[,3]
1             1000         37
1             50           18
1             3            54
1             90           72
1             25           23
2             NA           NA
3             4            15
4             NA           NA
5             2            20
5             7            19
etc           etc
```

Instead of NA's have:

```
Example[,1]   Example[,2]  Example[,3]
1             1000         37
1             50           18
1             3            54
1             90           72
1             25           23
2            5            20
3             4            15
4            3           15
5             2            20
5             7            19
etc           etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approch also works if your matrix has more than two columns. It's an extension of Joris Meys' solution.

```
Example <- matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,3,5,5,
                    1000,50,3,90,25,4,2,7,37,18,54,72,23,15,20,9),ncol=3)


diffs <- setdiff(Example[,2], Example[,1])
new_mat <- rbind(Example,
                 matrix(c(diffs,
                          rep(NA, length(diffs) * (ncol(Example) - 1))), 
                        ncol = ncol(Example)))
solution <- new_mat[order(new_mat[,1]),]
```

The result:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1 1000   37
 [2,]    1   50   18
 [3,]    1    3   54
 [4,]    1   90   72
 [5,]    1   25   23
 [6,]    2   NA   NA
 [7,]    3    4   15
 [8,]    4   NA   NA
 [9,]    5    2   20
[10,]    5    7    9
[11,]    7   NA   NA
[12,]   25   NA   NA
[13,]   50   NA   NA
[14,]   90   NA   NA
[15,] 1000   NA   NA
```

Once you have created this matrix, it's easy to generate a new one without NAs:

```
solution2 <- solution
solution2[is.na(solution2)] <- Example[match(sort(diffs), Example[,2]), -2]
```

The result:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1 1000   37
 [2,]    1   50   18
 [3,]    1    3   54
 [4,]    1   90   72
 [5,]    1   25   23
 [6,]    2    5   20
 [7,]    3    4   15
 [8,]    4    3   15
 [9,]    5    2   20
[10,]    5    7    9
[11,]    7    5    9
[12,]   25    1   23
[13,]   50    1   18
[14,]   90    1   72
[15,] 1000    1   37
```

Comment: this will alter the original data, please see above. Basically if I run this command some of the existing data will be destroyed.

Comment: basically the problem is only with the second part instead of match is there some other command which won't get rid of the other parts of the data?

Answer (score 3):

So, after you made clear what you want, this means you have a matrix

```
Example <- 
matrix(
  c(1,1,1,1,1,3,5,5,1000,50,3,90,25,4,2,7),
  ncol=2
)
```

Then you could do the following :

```
diffs <- setdiff(Example[,2],Example[,1])
tmps <- rbind(Example,
              matrix(
                 c(diffs,rep(NA,length(diffs))),
                 ncol=2
              )
        )
solution <- tmps[order(tmps[,1]),]
```

Which will give you the following result:

```
> solution
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1 1000
 [2,]    1   50
 [3,]    1    3
 [4,]    1   90
 [5,]    1   25
 [6,]    2   NA
 [7,]    3    4
 [8,]    4   NA
 [9,]    5    2
[10,]    5    7
[11,]    7   NA
...
```

See the help files `?matrix` and `?order`.

Comment: and does something similar apply if I'm trying to do this with vectors of different length?

Comment: is it clear what I'm asking or should I do something to make it more clear? I'm sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: You changed the question. You cannot combine two vectors of different length in a matrix, like in the original question. rethink what it is you want to do (do you have a matrix or not? which values do you want to add?), give the input, the expected output, and come back to us. If you keep on changing the question, it is impossible to answer.

Comment: Great! thank you very much this finally works! I have two additional and related questions. I really appreciate your help! I would really appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.